# Finding a particular expression in R

Tags: r

```
afn(a)
1       pwr_p08_mgr1       
2       pwr_p08_asd
3       pwr_p11_mgr1
4       pwr_p11_mgr4
5       pwr_p10_asd
6       scribbles
7       abc_de_p11_wer
8       red-p08
```

I have a function which will return a list of elements like what I labeled above. I want to repeat this for all possible values of a. There are 150 different values. For each of the values I want it to return 3 things. They can be 3 separate functions or all in 1 function. I want to get the periods present and count for each value of a. For the example shown, the period 08 appears 3 times, 10 once, and 11 3 times.  The other thing I need is the fraction of values of a (there are 150) for which each of the periods(01-50) are present.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input/output you want?

Have you had a look at the grep function? I think if you do a for in loop with a taking all the values you want it might work just fine. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/grep https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-the-first-for-loop-in-r/

Answer (score 2):

If we are extracting the first match of numbers and to find the frequency

```
library(stringr)
table(str_extract(afn_a, "\\d+"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work, if your character vector has this pattern: "XXX_p[0-9]XXX"
For example: The pattern for this string 'pwr_p08_mgr1' is 'XXX_X08_XXX1'. Numbers may appear before or after the first underscore, and the first numbered value will be taken as the return value.

```
afn_a <-  c( 'pwr_p08_mgr1', 'pwr_p08_asd', 'pwr_p11_mgr1',
             'pwr_p11_mgr4', 'pwr_p10_asd', 'scribbles',
             'abc_de_p11_wer', 'red-p08')

mytab <- table( na.omit( unlist( lapply( strsplit( gsub( "[^0-9_]", "", afn_a), split = "_"),
        function( x ){
          x[ x != "" ][1]
        }) ) ) ) 
mytab
# 08 10 11 
# 3  1  3 
mytab/150
# 08          10          11 
# 0.020000000 0.006666667 0.020000000
```